# Get data from kafka and send it to RSocket

Tags: reactjs, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, rsocket

I am trying to get messages from  kafka and send it to RSocket using Spring. Posting Server side on Spring Java and client side with React

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RsocketConsumerProperties.class)
public class RsocketConsumerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Function<Integer, Mono<Integer>> rsocketConsumer(RSocketRequester.Builder builder,
                                                            RsocketConsumerProperties rsocketConsumerProperties) {
        RSocketRequester rSocketRequester = builder.websocket(URI.create("ws://localhost:7000/"));
        return input -> rSocketRequester.route(rsocketConsumerProperties.getRoute()).data(input).retrieveMono(Integer.class);
    }
}
```

```
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class Listener {

    @Autowired
    private Function<Integer, Mono<Integer>> rsocketConsumer;


    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void fireAndForget(Integer val) {
        System.out.println(val);
        rsocketConsumer.apply(val).subscribe();
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class ServerController {

    @MessageMapping("data")
    public Mono<Integer> hello(Integer integer) {
        return Mono.just(integer);
    }

}
```

What do i do wrong in server side because my client is connected but not able to get new messages

```
  client.connect().subscribe({
    onComplete: socket => {
        socket.fireAndForget({
          data: { message: "hello from javascript!" },
          metadata: null
        });
      },
      onError: error => {
        console.log("got error");
        console.error(error);
      },
      onSubscribe: cancel => {
        /* call cancel() to abort */
        console.log("subscribe!");
        console.log(cancel);
        // cancel.cancel();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this `requester.route("input").data("Welcome to Rsocket").send();` where we have this:

```
   /**
     * Perform a {@link RSocket#fireAndForget fireAndForget} sending the
     * provided data and metadata.
     * @return a completion that indicates if the payload was sent
     * successfully or not. Note, however that is a one-way send and there
     * is no indication of whether or how the event was handled on the
     * remote end.
     */
    Mono<Void> send();
```

You see - `Mono`? That means that it has to be *subscribed* to initiate a reactive stream processing. See project Reactor for more info: https://projectreactor.io/

On the other hand it is not clear what is server and what is client in your case...
you do this:

```
    /**
     * Build an {@link RSocketRequester} with an
     * {@link io.rsocket.core.RSocketClient} that connects over WebSocket to
     * the given URL. The requester can be used to make requests
     * concurrently. Requests are made over a shared connection that is also
     * re-established as needed when further requests are made.
     * @param uri the URL to connect to
     * @return the created {@code RSocketRequester}
     * @since 5.3
     */
    RSocketRequester websocket(URI uri);
```

And I would say it means *client* in the code you show. The server is on the other side where that `7000` port is opened for `ws://` protocol. So, be sure that you understand and configure all the parts properly. For example I don't see why do you need a `@RestController` in your `Listener` class...

Comment: Hi Artem. Thanks for you reply. I corrected restcontroller as oit was not correct. What i am trying to do is to get messeges from kafka and then send them to rsocket. What would be you advice how to do it? I want to use spring to read messages from kafka and send them to react (javascript)

Comment: You go right way with the `RSocketRequester`. Only what you miss is a `subscribe()` to that `send()` result. you also may take a look into the latest Spring Cloud Stream with functional API and also investigate this project: https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream-applications. It has an `RScoket Sink` application for tasks like yours. Together with Kafka Binder you would achieve your goal with no code writing!

Comment: Hi Again. I am trying to use this one. Look like it what i need. https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/03/creating-a-function-for-consuming-data-and-generating-spring-cloud-stream-sink-applications. But I getting an error Field rsocketConsumer in com.healthservices.streaming.client.listener.Listener required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.Function' that could not be found. Tring to inject rsocketConsumer

Comment: Why do you write a custom app? What is wrong with that RSocket Sink from out-of-the-box? Anyway I think you are missing this one `spring.cloud.function.definition=rsocketConsumer` in the `application.properties` for your custom sink.

Comment: @meuhedetmeuhedet this is a helpful answer. You should consider accepting it (Using the V icon and for sure upvote it

Comment: i see that it fires with   rsocketConsumer.apply(val).subscribe(); Checking it with controller. But do not see it in react app

Comment: Probably that’s different story which deserves its own SO thread...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65463438/get-message-from-kafka-send-to-rsocket-and-revice-it-from-react-client