# Get Message From Kafka, send to Rsocket and Receive it from React client

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, rsocket

I am trying to send data from kafka using Spring cloud stream to Rsocket and then represent data on React

Here is my configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class RsocketConsumerConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public Sinks.Many<Data> sender(){
        return Sinks.many().multicast().directBestEffort();
    }
    

}
```

@Controller
public class   ServerController {

```
@Autowired
private Sinks.Many<Data> integer;

@MessageMapping("integer")
public Flux<Data> integer() {
    return  integer.asFlux();
}
```

```
@EnableBinding(IClientProcessor.class)
public class Listener {

    @Autowired
    private Sinks.Many<Data> integer;

    @StreamListener(IClientProcessor.INTEGER)
    public void integer(Data val) {
        System.out.println(val);
        integer.tryEmitNext(val);
    }

}
```

```
   let  client = new RSocketClient({
    transport: new RSocketWebSocketClient(
        {
            url: 'ws://localhost:7000/ws',
            wsCreator: (url) => new WebSocket(url),
            debug: true,
        },
        BufferEncoders,
    ),
    setup: {
        dataMimeType: "application/json",
        metadataMimeType: MESSAGE_RSOCKET_COMPOSITE_METADATA.string,
        keepAlive: 5000,
        lifetime: 60000,
    },
});

  client
            .then(rsocket => {
                console.log("Connected to rsocket");
                rsocket.requestStream({
                    metadata: Buffer.from(encodeCompositeMetadata([
                        [MESSAGE_RSOCKET_ROUTING, encodeRoute("integer")],
                    ])),
                 
                })
                    .subscribe({
                        onSubscribe: s => {
                            s.request(2147483647)
                        },
                        onNext: (p) => {
                            let newData = {
                                time: new Date(JSON.parse(p.data).time).getUTCSeconds(),
                                integer: JSON.parse(p.data).integer
                            }
                           newData.integer >100?setInteger(currentData => [newData, ...currentData]):setInt(currentData => [newData, ...currentData])
                           console.log(newData)
                        },
                        onError: (e) => console.error(e),
                        onComplete: () => console.log("Done")
                    });
```

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.integer.destination=integer
Not able to see it in react app. Please advise. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: updated question with the answer

Comment: @meuhedetmeuhedet: Don't update the question text with a solution! It is better if you post the solution as an answer to your own question! You can also mark your own answer as accepted. It that way it is easy for readers to see that the problem is solved. Also, readers can vote on your answer. :)

Comment: @Lii lots of new code. where do i put it?

Comment: @meuhedetmeuhedet. I don't understand... Can't you put the code in code blocks in the answer text?

Comment: will be to long and ugly

Comment: The Q&A aspect is the critical point of stackoverflow.  Without that it's just asking random strangers on the internet to debug your program for you.

Comment: I mean it probably what it is. Asking random stranger to debug your code. In a orginized way

Answer (score 1):

Given the data appears to be going directly from Kafka (via Spring) to the client, perhaps it would make more sense to [stream Kafka messages via an internet-messaging broker to Internet-facing clients over WebSockets](https://www.ably.io/topic/websockets-kafka).

Disclosure: I am not the author of that article, but do work at that company where the author works. We see this use case frequently, so expect this approach may be useful.